# How do i make objects in Flash AS2 less blurry when moving?

Tags: flash, actionscript-2

I have a simple game, which my object which I control is blurry, and I use AS2. This is the code I used, it's very simple:

```
onClipEvent (load) {

power = 0.3;
yspeed = 0;
xspeed = 0;
friction = 0.95;
gravity = 0.5;
thrust = 3.75;
wind = 0.18;
_root.level1_text.text = 0+collected_coin19;
reverse = new Sound();
reverse.attachSound("hit2");



}
onClipEvent (enterFrame) {
if (Key.isDown(Key.LEFT)) {
    xspeed -= power;
}
if (Key.isDown(Key.RIGHT)) {
    xspeed += power;
}
if (Key.isDown(1)) {
    yspeed -= power*thrust;
}
if (Key.isDown(Key.SPACE)) {
    yspeed -= power*thrust;
}
xspeed += wind;
xspeed *= friction;
yspeed += gravity;
_y += yspeed;
_x += xspeed;
```

Comment: I forgot to say that it is 60 fps, so that shouldn't be a problem

Answer (score 0):

The version of AS is probably not the issue.

I know the style of the game you are emulating is pixelated. Is your object a bitmap? If so you might want to try vector art.

Either way, be sure the bird is pixel perfect, at 100% size, and its position is on an integer rather than a decimal. Even pixel fonts can look blurry in Flash if their size and location don't insure the fidelity of the pixels.

Comment: I know all that, position is 240 and 30 so no decimals, also how do i change it to vector? Right now my "hero" is a green square 32x32 pixels, so image is not the problem, if i put something a bit more complex it looks terrible

Comment: Flash has vector editing capabilities, but I typically build in Illustrator. GL

Answer (score 0):

Another idea for you is to do the image at like 200% the original size, with a little pixelating, then shrink it down to the 100%, this way it'll have less pixelation issues, as it's normally caused by enlarging images, but is reversed when shrunk

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a bitmap image trace the bitmap and convert it to a movie clip. Within trace bitmap you can set the settings you need to in order to remove pixelation.

Good luck let me know if you need clarification!